# How to query for info from 2 tables with sequelize

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I have two tables: Class and Course. Each Class has a course_id that defines what type of course it is on the Course table. Here are my models:

```
const Class = sequelize.define('class', {
  class_date: Sequelize.DATE,
  begin_time: Sequelize.TIME,
  end_time: Sequelize.TIME,
  max_capacity: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  is_published: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  training_facility_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  state_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  registration_deadline: Sequelize.DATE,
  course_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  is_report_60_generated: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  completed_by_user_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true
})

const Course = sequelize.define('course', {
  code: Sequelize.STRING,
  name: Sequelize.STRING
 }, {
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true
})
```

When I hit the classes endpoint, I get a array of classes. How would I set up the query to respond with the course name and code for each class instead of just the course_id?

Comment: You need to create an association/relationship, and the type depends on your data model. One to one, one to many, etc...

Comment: So it'll be one-to-many if there are many classes and can each have only one course name? Would it look like Course.hasMany(Class, {as: 'Classes'}) ?

Comment: Yes, I re-read your question and saw what you were doing, just posted an answer with the relationship definition/query. Basically what you have, except you probably want to specify the column as `NOT NULL`, and since it's auto-created you don't need it in our model definition. Sequelize documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [create a relationship](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/associations/) between the `Class` and `Course` models. If you specify the `underscored: true` option in the Model definition it won't use camel case and will automatically create the `Class.course_id` column, so you don't need to define it (the same probably goes for `completed_by_user_id`).

```js
const Class = sequelize.define('class', {
  class_date: Sequelize.DATE,
  begin_time: Sequelize.TIME,
  end_time: Sequelize.TIME,
  max_capacity: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  is_published: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  training_facility_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  state_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  registration_deadline: Sequelize.DATE,

  // this will be auto-created by the relationship
  // course_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,

  is_report_60_generated: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  // you probably want a relationship here as well
  completed_by_user_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true,

  // use underscored names
  underscored: true,
})

const Course = sequelize.define('course', {
  code: Sequelize.STRING,
  name: Sequelize.STRING
 }, {
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  underscored: true,
})
```

Based on your data model it seems as though each `Class` will require an associated `Course` with different attributes like start time, etc, so you will tell Sequelize that each `Class` [`belongsTo()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/associations/#1m) a `Course`.

```js
// tell Sequelize that once course will be assigned to many classes, and it is required (not null)
Class.belongsTo(Course, { foreignKey: { allowNull: false } })
```

Once they are related you can use the [`include` option](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/#relations-associations) value to specify a model to join to your primary query. If you use `as` in the relationship you must specify it here as well.

```js
// do a joined query using "include"
Class.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Course
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'm getting this error though: "course (Courses) is not associated to class!"

Comment: D'oh, I copied some of my code but I am querying the data differently. Try removing the `as` parameter from both and see if it works...

Comment: Took 'as' off from both, still getting this though: course is not associated to class!

Comment: I updated the answer, pretty sure you need to use `belongsTo()` since each `Class` has one `Course` - seemed to create the correct schema in my testing. Since you aren't using `as` leave it off everywhere.

Comment: If you want to be able to do both `Class.getCourses()` and `Course.getClass()` you need to define the relationship in both directions, meaning both `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()`.

Comment: ok i think that part is working, I get 'column class.courseId does not exist', how can i set the foreign key to course_id instead if that's the issue?

Comment: use `underscored: true,` in the model definition. see updated answer.

Comment: Works now! Thanks a lot for being so thorough :)

Comment: Ha, I actually have to update some of my code now based on my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129481/discussion-between-matt-aft-and-doublesharp).